# Angular UI modal prematurely loading

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router, bootstrap-modal

I'm using the AngularUI Bootstrap Modal and the AngularUI Router. The modal is displaying before the Select button is clicked. Any suggestions on how to prevent this from happening?

HTML:

```
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal-header">
  <h3 class="modal-title">Title</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <form name="myForm">

  <div class="control-group form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="editProject.project.name">
  </div>

  <label>Description</label>
  <textarea name="description" class="form-control" ng-model="editProject.project.description"></textarea>

  <div class="modal-footer">
  <button ng-click="editProject.cancel()" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
  <button ng-click="editProject.save()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"
        class="btn btn-primary" >Save</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>

<!-- Button that triggers modal -->

<a ui-sref="selection.new">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="open()">Select</button>
   </a>
```

Router:

```
.state('selection.new', {
url: '/new',
onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', '$resource', function ($stateParams, $state, $modal, $resource) {
$modal.open({
templateUrl: 'views/new-mark.html',
controller: 'NewProjectCtrl as editProject'})
                    .result.finally(function () {
                        $state.go('^');
                    });
        }]
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

From angular ui-router

> There are also optional 'onEnter' and 'onExit' callbacks that get
>   called when a state becomes active and inactive respectively. The
>   callbacks also have access to all the resolved dependencies.

So, `onEnter` function is called before another state functions.

You should move your code to state's controller.

```
.state('selection.new', {
url: '/new',
controller: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', '$resource', function ($stateParams, $state, $modal, $resource) {
$modal.open({
templateUrl: 'views/new-mark.html',
controller: 'NewProjectCtrl as editProject'})
                    .result.finally(function () {
                        $state.go('^');
                    });
           // });
        }]
    })
```

Comment: When I use the code you posted above, the modal will no longer open. Any suggestions?